# Express.js render partial view without jade

Tags: express, template-engine, pug

I'm new to Node and Express. In the default app created by Express I found out that the partial rendering is done in jade through these lines (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
// layout.jade
body
    block content

// index.jade
block content
    h1= title
```

Having worked with a php framework, this is kind of new for me. Apparently, the partial rendering is not handled by Express anymore as of today. How does it work now?

Thanks.

Edit: by the way, anyone knows what happened to the Express documentation? The official site's guide section shrank by a lot (or perhaps it's just me).

Comment: it shrank because they removed a lot of features to make things more simple (ie no partials or dynamic helpers).

Comment: but now how to render a partial?? using res.render???

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jonathan, I'd checkmark it if it was a formal answer. Andrescabana: templates are likely handled by the the templating engines themselves now. Jade includes that functionality. Go check the main github page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The partial rendering is indeed done by the templating system now. Express 3.0+ decided to keep it simple and removed the built-in partial rendering functionality.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x